# Apexcharts Angular tickPlacement issue when using combo chart

Tags: angular, apexcharts, ng-apexcharts

I've created a combo chart using 3 series, one step-line and two column.

You can see a [working demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/apx-combo-line-column-forked-2qyzkj).

The issue:
Step-line data point goes in between the two columns.
[in the docs](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/xaxis/) there is a tickPlacement section, I would like to use the 'on' option. I've changed the `xaxis.type` to 'category' but it's not working.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance